# How to override a method exist in GWT Module (A) in other module (B)?

Tags: gwt

I have 1 GWT module(A). 
I don't have code of module (A) only output jar file of module A.
(Module A is provided by other application)

I want to override a method of Module (A) in another custom module (B) so when application gets loaded it should execute method from module (B) i.e. override the method from Module (A)

Is it possible to override a method in GWT ? If yes then how ?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on exactly what you mean? How does one GWT module have one method, but a different module have a single method? Overriding a method by _extending_ a class is a normal java concept, and works fine in Java, but I doubt this is what you mean.

Comment: My question would be: what's in the "output jar file of module A"?

Comment: Sorry for confusion.
I will try to explain again.
Module A has its own set of java classes and methods ( along with resources like js , ii8n etc), It is provided by application so I don't have access to code of  Module A. 
I wanted to override the default behaviour one of the method from Module A by creating my own custom Module B.

But today I found that Module A provided some extension points (published interfaces) to override the method using GIN ( GWT injection) .
Using GIN I was able to override the method. 

Thank you for taking out time to write.